# how to count number of distinct values of a field from two collections in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, distinct

I have to mongoDB collection A and B. Both of them have the field 'user'.
I would like to know the number of distinct users in A, B, and (A + B). 
Pseudo code would be like the following:

```
A.user.distinct().count()
B.user.distinct().count()
(A.user union B.user)..distinct().count()
```

Can someone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [**`count()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#db-collection-count) with `distinct`  to get the number of distinct users in your collection because It is not an array method and `distinct` returns an array. You need to use the [**`Array.length`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property

To get the number of distinct users in A or B use the following

```
db.A.distinct('user').length
db.B.distinct('user').length
```

To get the number of distinct users in A union B use [**`Array.prototype.concat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var users = db.A.distinct('user');
users = users.concat(db.B.distinct('user'));
var num = users.filter(function(u, pos) {return users.indexOf(u) == pos; });
num.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of distinct users in each collection you can run the following in the `mongo` shell:

```js
db.A.distinct("user").length;
db.B.distinct("user").length;
```

To get the number of distinct users in the union of `A` and `B` I would first retrieve the distinct arrays for each collection and then do a union of the arrays and find the length. If you're using JavaScript, I would recommend using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#)' `union()` method to do it. Its usage is explained [here](http://underscorejs.org/#union). Note that you can load Underscore.js (or any JavaScript file) to the `mongo` shell by running the following command from within the shell:

```js
load("path/to/underscore.js");
```

Then you can easily run the following:

```js
var a = db.A.distinct("user");
var b = db.B.distinct("user");
_.union(a, b).length;
```

Otherwise you can implement your own JavaScript function, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items), or one in the language of your application.

Comment: Truly appreciate your descent solution. I am picking Michael9's solution since it is more native (without the need to load other js packages)